# Why is my loop running even when the condition is false?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int no,tr_no;
char val;
int main (void) {
    void getno(void);
    void getval(void);
    void printall(int number);
    void printonly(int number);
    void print(void);

    getval();
    getno();

    if (val=='a')
        printall(no);

    if (val=='o')
        printonly(no);

    return 0;
}

void getval(void) { 
    printf("enter o for only 1 triangular number\n");
    printf("enter a for all the triangular number from 1 to that number\n");

    scanf(" %c",&val);

    while (val!='a' || val!='o') {
        printf("enter valid char\n");
        getval();
    }       
}
```

The while loop should not run when `val==a` or `val==o`, but it still does. Not only a while loop, also an if statement does not work. However when there is only 1 condition, i.e.

```
if (val!=a)
getval();
```

it works!!

```
void getno(void)
{
    printf("enter number for which tr no needs to be found\n");
    scanf("%i",&no);
}
void printall(int number)
{
    int i;
    tr_no=0;
    void print(void);
    for (i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
        tr_no=tr_no+i;
        printf("The %ith tr_no is\n",i);
        print();
    }
}
void printonly(int number)
{
    void print(void);
    tr_no=0;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
        tr_no=tr_no+i;
    }
print();
}
void print(void)
{
    printf("%i\n",tr_no);
}
```

In the getval function, even when the value of val is entered as a or o or any other values, the loop keeps running. Please help.

Comment: (val!='a' || val!='o') is always true

Comment: `val != 'a' || val != 'o'`. Ok, let's test it for `val = 'a'`. When `val = 'a'`, then `val != 'a'` is false and `val != 'o'` is true. The `||` works like an OR, so `false || true` is `true`. So the loop will run.

Comment: Tangential to your main issue(s) — You should place the function declarations outside of `main()`, and you should put the variable definitions inside `main()`.  Avoid global variables when possible.  Functions are globally accessible; declaring them inside a function is moderately pointless.

Comment: Don't use recursion in your `getval` function, use loops. Otherwise you could end up with a denial-of-service attack where someone could exhaust the stack.

Comment: And don't use global variables! Instead have the function *return* the value.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is `val!='a' || val!='o'`. Let's run through a couple examples here:

- Supposed `val == 'b'`. Then `val != 'a'` is true, and `val != 'o'` is true, and or-ing them together is `true || true`, which is true.
- Suppose `val == 'a'`. Then `val != 'a'` is false, but `val != 'o'` is true, so or-ing them together is `false || true`, which is true.
- Suppose `val == 'o'`. This is almost equivalent to the previous case; `true || false` is true.

The problem is that inverting the whole condition isn't the same as inverting each component. If you want the loop to run until `val == 'a'` or until `val == 'o'`, you want something equivalent to `while (! (val == 'a' || val == 'o'))`. In this case, [de Morgan's law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html) says that you need to change the `==`s to `!=`s, *and* change the `||` to an `&&`. You want it to loop while `val` isn't `'a'` *and* `val` isn't `'o'`.

Comment: Remember that the `&&` and `||` operators do short circuit evaluation.  For your first supposition (`val == 'b'`), then `val != 'a'` is true, so the short circuit evaluation kicks in and the result is true without ever testing `val != 'o'`.  The second case is described accurately; the third case only evaluates `val != 'a'` and because that's true, it never evaluates `val != 'o'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but as `val != 'o'` doesn't have side effects, I thought simplifying would be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` in your loop condition

```
while (val!='a' && val!='o')
```

otherwise it's an endless loop, because your loop condition (`(val!='a' || val!='o')`) is always true.